# While creating table how to identify the data types in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am learning to use Hadoop for performing Big Data related operations.

I need to perform some queries on a collection of data sets split across 8 csv files. Each csv file has multiple sheets and the query concerns only one of the sheets(Sheet Name: Table4)

The dataset can be downloaded here : http://www.census.gov/hhes/www/hlthins/data/utilization/tables.html

[Sample Data snap shot attached for quick reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvFI5.jpg)

I have already converted the above xls file to csv.

**Am not sure how to group the data while creating table in Hive.**

It will be really helpful if you can guide me here.

Note: I am a novice with Hadoop and Big Data, so if anyone could guide me with how to proceed further I'd be very grateful.

If you need information on the queries or anything else let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything to accomplish this? If not, because of you are novice to hadoop, then setup hadoop and hive installation and try to write simple logics like word-count then go for JOINS and advance topics. You can refer this [hive tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/).